# "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource" - Unity WebGL AWS S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cors, unity-webgl

When storing a Unity WebGL project on AWS S3, and retrieving it from another domain, it gives the CORS error:

"XMLHttpRequest cannot load. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource"

This error only occurs for the .unityweb files, the .json and .js files work fine.

---

A lot of the old solutions to this problem don't work anymore, but I found a newer one that does hidden away in some comment. I thought it'd be easier to create a new question and answer it myself in case anyone else needs it.

Answer (score 2):

In your S3 bucket go to permissions, and select the CORS configuration.
Paste this in:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
<AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
<AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
<AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
<AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
<AllowedMethod>HEAD</AllowedMethod>
<AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

The 'HEAD' allowed method is the important one, that allows .unityweb files to be retrieved.

Comment: Spent me hours and finally found this!